# showing Boolean algebra equality

Tags: boolean-algebra

I have this exercise in my worksheet : 

 
Show that
**x (z ⊕ y) =  xz ⊕ xy** 
I reached this in solving it , but didn't reach the final equation 
 x(z'y + zy')
 xz'y + xzy'
 please can someone show how

Comment: What does it mean that you "reached this" but "didn't reach the final equation"?  What is the final equation?

Comment: Isn't that an *axiom* of boolean algebras? What's your definition of a boolean algebra?

Comment: sorry fixed the question recheck it

Comment: Isn't it now an application of a DeMorgan law distributing AND over OR?

Comment: yes it is all AND and OR

Answer (score 0):

The truth table shows that both expressions are in fact equivalent:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Checking the above expression with the truth table is the best option.
There is another crude way to prove the same.

xz ⊕ xy = xz (xy)' +(xz) 'xy

```
      = xz (x'+ y') + (x'+ z') xy
      = xx'z + xzy' + x'xy + xyz'       xx'=0 and yy'=0
      = xzy' + xyz'
      = x ( zy' + yz')
      = x (y ⊕ z)
```